# C++20 No more dependent scope needed

Tags: c++, c++20

I have upgraded to `c++20` recently and noticed that the compiler doesnt throw an error when i dont put `typename` infront of a dependent cope type alias e.g.

```
using iterator = (no typename here) std::vector<int>::iterator
```

Is this now part of the new c++20 standart or is it just a gcc thing and not all compilers do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a C++20 thing:

> In some contexts, only type names can validly appear. In these contexts, a dependent qualified name is assumed to name a type and no typename is required:

> - A qualified name that is used as a declaration specifier in the (top-level) decl-specifier-seq of:
>
>   - a simple declaration or function definition at namespace scope;
>   - a class member declaration;
>   - a parameter declaration in a class member declaration (including friend function declarations), outside of default arguments;
>   - a parameter declaration of a declarator for a function or function template whose name is qualified, outside of default arguments;
>   - a parameter declaration of a lambda expression outside of default arguments;
>   - a parameter declaration of a requires-expression;
>   - the type in the declaration of a non-type template parameter;
> - A qualified name that appears in type-id, where the smallest enclosing type-id is:
>
>   - the type in a new expression that does not parenthesize its type;
>   - the type-id in an alias declaration;
>   - a trailing return type,
>   - a default argument of a type template parameter, or
>   - the type-id of a static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast, or reinterpret_cast.

see [dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) for more details.